# PDF: Select All does not select parts of text

Tags: pdf, extract

I have a problem with selecting whole text in PDF page. When using Edit->Select All most of the text is selected, but some parts remains unselected:
[image]

I'm working with editable pdf, generated by the system. Is there any way to really select all text within this document? How can I reach those missing parts?
(Those missing parts can be selected by mouse double click)
I'm using Adobe Acrobat Pro X.

After furhter investigation I've realised that when I choose Select tool and want to select one of those areas here's error message which appears:
[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a site for every question remotely related to computers. It is for *programming questions* only.

Comment: This is kind-of programming question. I need to find a way how to extract those information for RPA process which I'm doing right now.

Comment: Of course it is a *kind-of* programming question - because it has to do with *computers*. But did you program Acrobat Pro X? (In which case, please include the problematic code in your question.) Are you using another programming language for this "Select All"?

Comment: *"How can I reach those missing parts?"* - can you share the pdf for analysis?

Comment: Unfortunatelly - I can't. After further investigation I realised that there's an error message which appears when I want to select one of those areas. The other thing is that when I want to export it to e.g. Word document those parts which can not be selected are misisng as well.

Comment: probably those not-selected texts are in annotations, e.g. form field widgets.

Comment: does those fields have name or ID? Is there a way to programatically reach those (e.g. .VB.NET)?